# How to upload selected file from Android to Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I have the following codes to browse files from SD Card in Android. 
**But how do I implement codes such that the selected file can be uploaded to a specified bucket in Amazon S3?** Please help, thank you very much.

```
    package sg.edu.nyp.sit.s3;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class FilePickS3Activity extends ListActivity {

private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
private String root="/";
private TextView myPath;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
    getDir(root);
}

private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);

    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();

    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {

        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);

        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());

    }

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
            File file = files[i];
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory())
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            else
                item.add(file.getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    File file = new File(path.get(position));

    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        if(file.canRead())
            getDir(path.get(position));
        else
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    }).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, I am using AWS Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transfer the data programmatically then you can use the AWS SDK:

http://aws.amazon.com/de/sdkforandroid/

There is a online documentation with examples: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4225549089557252

Comment: Hi, which part is the one for uploading of files. I believe in AWSAndroidDemo sample, it only shows the bucket list. How do I implement in the uploading codes?

Comment: Just readout entire demo sample. there is a option to share the file to amazon s3.

Comment: I've downloaded the aws-android-sdk-1.0.4 from http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/. But there are many java files in the src folders. I'm not sure how do I open and implement them in Eclipse. Would you mind to give some advice?